# Phonegap Build Windows Phone change pin to start text

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, build

So i've been building a windows phone app with phonegap build. I'm using the config.xml file. Does anyone know how to change the pin to start text?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to Phonegap Build but I had exactly the same problem when building a WP8 app locally. I found the only way to change this is by doing the following:

1. In your Phonegap project, open **platforms\wp8\Properties\WMAppManifest.xml** in a text editor.
2. Change the value of **Title**.
3. Un-pin the app and then re-pin. The title should now be updated.

This doesn't feel like the right way to do this but changing the PhoneGap config.xml doesn't seem to make any difference.